# How do you run a vim command that is the text inside a buffer?

Tags: vim

For example lets say this text is inside buffer

```
%s/a/b/gI
```

How do I run that as a vim command, without typing it inside the vim command line.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You can yank the text--even multiple lines--then type:

```
:@"
```

(That's colon, at symbol, double quote.)

In fact you could yank it to a named register, such as `a`, and do:

```
:@a
```

See:

```
:help :@
```

Answer (score 2):

In command mode:

You yank the text, say if it was on its own line

`y$`

then type

`:`

then

`<ctrl-r> "`